# React Redux Form Character counter on textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux-form

I have a form built with [React-Redux-Form](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs.html) and need to implement and display a character count to limit the input to 200. I have implemented the validation for it but want to display the characters number while the user types.

Here's my control:

```
<div className="input-group">
  <label>Step 2: Description of Goods *</label>
  <Control.textarea
   id="descriptionOfGoods"
   model=".descriptionOfGoods"
   name="descriptionOfGoods"
   autoComplete="off"
   className="form-control"
   controlProps={{onKeyPress:_preventCarriageReturn}}
   mapProps={{..._mapFieldClass}}
   validators={{isRequired, remoteError, maxLength: (val) => maxLength(val, 200)}}
   onChange={(e) => this.removeApiError(e)}
  />

  <span className="tick-valid"><Icon yicon="Validation_Tick"/></span>
  <span className="cross-error"><Icon yicon="X"/></span>
  <Errors 
   id="descriptionOfGoodsErrors"
   className="help-block"
   model=".descriptionOfGoods"
   show={{touched: true, focus: false}}
   messages={{
     isRequired: 'Description of goods is required.',
     remoteError: validationError.descriptionOfGoods,
     maxLength: 'Max characters allowed is 200'
   }}
  />
</div>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

For the text area, you'll need to listen to three events. One for onKeyUp, one for onPaste, and one for onCut. Then whenever one of those events are triggered, you can get the current text in the textarea to determine the current length, and use that value to update a span which can show the number of characters left.

Comment: In modern browsers you can just listen for the `input` event.